# Prevent "hg status" from showing everything under untracked directories

Tags: mercurial

I find the output of `hg status` too verbose for untracked directories. Suppose I have an empty repository that's managed by both `git` and `hg`. So there would be two directories, `.git` and `.hg`.

The output of `git status` is:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .hg/
```

The output of `hg status` is:

```
? .git/HEAD
? .git/config
? .git/description
? .git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
? .git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
? .git/hooks/post-commit.sample
? .git/hooks/post-receive.sample
? .git/hooks/post-update.sample
? .git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
? .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
? .git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
? .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
? .git/hooks/update.sample
? .git/info/exclude
```

Is there a way to reduce its output to something like the following line?

```
? .git/
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just add in your `.hgignore` file

```
 syntax:glob
.git
.gitattributes
.gitignore
```

To ignore `.git` entirely, and other git-related files.

If the goal is to only limit to a directory, you can still use `.hgignore` if you add an hidden file in that directory (after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048628/hgignore-syntax-for-ignoring-only-files-not-directories/1742404#1742404)):

```
 syntax:regexp
 ^.git/(?!\.hidden).+$
```

Since Mercurial do not track directories at all, that will ignore all files within `.git` except the hidden one, effectively displaying only one line in the status.

You would also have the option `-q/--quiet` (to `hg status`), which hides untracked (unknown and ignored) files unless explicitly requested with `-u/--unknown` or `-i/--ignored`.
But that means `.git` would not even show up in that case.

---

But if the goal is to limit *in general* the output of hg status to only the directories and not their content for untracked files, then I believe this is not possible:

- git track content of files and since no content is added, it only mentions the top directory has "having no content added"
- mercurial tracks files (not directories), hence the comprehensive list (of *files*).

Comment: That's not my point. I used the `.git` directory just as an example.

Comment: @Wei: right, I have completed my answer to reflect your actual question

Comment: It's `syntax:regexp`, not `regex`, accorging to manual (and will throw a warning): http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html

Comment: @noinstance well spotted. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Well I spotted because I copy pasted and didn't work. Would have edited but couldn't as it was only one char. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

This works for me :

```
hg status -q
```

> Option `-q`/`--quiet` hides untracked (unknown and ignored) files unless  explicitly requested with `-u`/`--unknown` or `-i`/`--ignored`.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the question is about how to reduce the output: I had similar need but did not want to untrack or ignore files. If you are using *NIX, you cloud use grep, and you just want to reduce the output as your question states, for example to get rid of these lines:

```
hg status | grep -v "^\?\s\.git"
```

Or for example not showing removed files

```
hg status | grep -v "^R"
```

In Windows PowerShell an equivalent would be:

```
hg status | Select-String -Pattern ("^[^R]")
```